# Retrieving data from many tables with simple output

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have tables with similar structure (with same columns), but with different info, can I retrieve it's data in the same output as a simple MySQl query (`SELECT * FROM table where Name="Boo";`)?

Ex.:

```
SELECT * FROM Weapon, Armor, Helm, Bomb, Potion where Name="Boo";
```

**RESULT**

```
   ID    Name    Position.X    Position.Y        Item     TableName
   23    Boo       3                0           Gun        (Weapon)
   11    Boo       2                1           Cloth      (Armor)
   74    Boo       0                4           Tunic      (Armor)
   119   Boo       7                5           Coif       (Helm)
   9     Boo       1                6           Crown      (Helm)
   81    Boo       3                2           Grenade    (Bomb)
   44    Boo       8                1           Grenade    (Bomb)
   32    Boo       0                6           Small      (Potion)
   98    Boo       6                4           Big        (Potion)
```

I have a system with set of tables (like 8) which, in some cases have the exactly same structure, and in others it's slightly different (one or two different columns).

Each table stores info about a user items and where they're stored.

I tried `INNER JOIN`, but it messed the results.

Comment: "*tables with similar structure (with same columns)*"—this is generally indicative of a schema that violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).  **Don't do it** (without good reason).

Comment: Looks like you Need a union

Comment: @eggyal, I don't think it violates this principle. I mean, what is the structure used for games? You have a multitude of items types (armor, weapon, potion etc.), for every item type you have another list of item graduations (small weapon, medium weapon, bigger weapon etc.), then you have the players. How would you store all those info? The user inventory? I have seen two ways: one having individual table for storing each item type (Weapon, Potion etc.); and the other an Inventory table storing items in hexadecimal values (FF0020311ABB248912).

Comment: @RafaelVidal: You haven't really provided enough information to give a definitive answer, but *in extremis* you could use the [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: @eggyal, yes, you're right. I'm wondering, because there is always a better method to do something. Do you know any model for games inventory? Can you tell me from your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables `Weapon, Armor, Helm, Bomb, Potion` have all the same structure  You can use Union

```
  SELECT * FROM Weapon where Name="Boo" 
  union  
  SELECT * FROM Armor where Name="Boo"         
  union 
  SELECT * FROM Helm where Name="Boo"       
  union  
  SELECT * FROM Bomb where Name="Boo"       
  union  
  SELECT * FROM Potion  where Name="Boo" ;
```

Otherwise you can set the proper column name  for each select. 
In union clause the column must are of the same type and in the same number

Comment: @RafaelVidal ... but see eggyal's comment above

Comment: Coluld be the original question is not in the correct normal form but ... the OP question about have retrive data  ....yes is right ... check also for the correct data design ..

Comment: @scaisEdge, how can I adapt this for tables with different columns? Supposing Armor and Helm has same columns, but Potion has an additional column. Could I still retrieve all columns from all tables leaving it empty if column doesn't exist for that table? And can it show from which table which row refers?

Comment: @RafaelVidal ALWAYS name the columns you actually want returned

Comment: If Armor and Hel have same column and Potion has an additional column .. then  select using column name (in each select the column name may be different .. the important things is the corresponding column in each select  must have the same typpe

Comment: @scaisEdge, I didn't get you. Suppose on ARMOR and HELM I have columns: "ID", "Defense", "Protection" and "Name"; while on POTION: "ID", "RecoverRatio", "Name". How could I retrieve the info? (PS: it's just a simplified supposition)

Comment: @Strawberry, why not to retrieve them all?

Comment: @RafaelVidal  in the case of Potion you missing a column then substitute with a fixed value ..

Comment: @RafaelVidal Because it's bad practice, negatively impacts performance, and leads to problems like the one you describe. If you want to select a column in one table that doesn't exist in another table you can use NULL as a placeholder.

Comment: @scaisEdge, ok. The other question: can I see from which table which row refers? Is it possible to ORDER the results?

Comment: Firts When you type the select you can add a column wth the name fo the table .. second .. yes .. you can order the result .. (you can use the alias in the firts select and sort by these alias  )

Comment: @scaisEdge, help me one step further. I'm having to look over all those tables, because some items are in the same Position (x, y), and, therefore, causing issues. I'm trying to associate X and Y positions in a way that I can see which item(s) is(are) stuck in the same position and causing bug.

Comment: @RafaelVidal   I suggest you  of post a new proper and specific question with  clear data  samples so i   (and the community) can eval your need ... and eventually comment me the new link